# Ruby Enter Your Password to Create App

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, sudo, ruby

I have just installed ruby on rails on a Centos server with directadmin following http://blog.ilwilliams.net/installing-rails-3-with-apache-on-centos/

I'm now in a non privileged user account (without sudo) and am trying to create an application using `rails new personal`

However this does the following

```
     create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
      create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
      create  vendor/plugins
      create  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
         run  bundle install
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Sorry, try again.
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
joe is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Is there a way to allow users to create apps and use ruby without having to be logged in as root or ever use sudo, I believe the problem is occuring as rails is trying to install the app to the servers gem folder rather than once for the user?

Any ideas much appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should install RVM on their accounts.

Then use RVM to install rails and it gems using bundle.

Comment: What do I need to remove first before installing RVM as I already have both ruby and gems installed!

Comment: You should not need to remove anything, just install rvm and then use rvm to install ruby and rails.

Comment: But I already have both ruby, rails and passenger installed, wont there be collisions?

Comment: No, that is what RVM is for, dealing with multiple versions on the same machine.